# References, references, references. .

Tags: discussion, references

I've already posted a few questions on meta regarding details about the references we should have on answers. I have some more ideas on the topic, but I don't think that simply posting more meta questions is going to get anywhere. So this question is intended to be a discussion regarding references in answers (and questions, if you feel those are necessary). I invite everyone to post an answer discussing his/her opinion on what the references in answers should be like. Here are some suggestions for points you could address:

- What types of sources should be used (books, websites, podcasts (!?), etc.)?
- Which sources should be allowed (papers/pre-prints, Wikipedia, encyclopedias, primary sources).
- How many sources should be used in each answer?
- Should there be quotations of sources in an answer?

Or, you could simply argue that we shouldn't hold answers on the site to any standard.

Answer (score 4):

I actually want to argue that we shouldn't hold answers on the site to any standard (though this sounds quite negative this way).

To formalize some standard for citations is not a suitable way to maintain or achieve a high standard on this site. Moreover, it should also be acknowledged that the types of questions are quite mixed, from idle/general interest to more serious or even research-oriented ones.

What type of reference are suitable really depends on the question. Personally, I used all kinds of things already, from original papers form the 19th century over scholarly articles to a presentation hosted on some slide-sharing site. Of course, the last is not the best possible reference, but I did not find a better one, and the alternative would have been to give none, or to suppress some piece of information that felt relevant to me.

Moreover, I believe that to insist on things like, you should not cite Wikipedia rather might alienate some people for not that much in return. I can imagine good answers that only use Wikipedia as reference and I can imagine quite bad ones that cite all kinds of printed things.

A podcast by an established researcher could be easily a more credible sources than some popular science (history) book, of which there are quite a few, of quite mixed quality.

Generally speaking, if one feels an answer is lacking in some way, such as not having enough references to back up what it says, one can comment and ask for this to be provide, and/or vote accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd expect out of a good answer:

- **No Wikipedia as the primary (or even secondary, really) source in an answer.** I love it as much as anyone, but it won't necessarily be accurate in many of these cases, and accuracy is all-important here. (I'm okay with using it tangentially, though. For example, if you quote a text as "And [scientist X]'s work in abstract algebra and [group theory](Wikipedia link) was extremely important to the development of abstract algebra", I'd be fine with the Wikipedia link so long as the topic of the question was abstract algebra, and group theory was only tangentially related.)
- **Books are really good, but only if you can refer users to a transcript online or they are readily accessible.** For example, some users are fond of quoting semi-obscure texts that, while valid, are hard to find. Before I upvote an answer, I like to check for myself that the user's interpretation of the source is correct. I (and many others, most likely) do not have access to a university database or a large library, so it can be nearly impossible to verify certain book sources. On the other hand, citing Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's *Gravitation* would be okay because it is relatively easy to find.
- **Hyperlinks, please.** For websites, it would be great if the user can add hyperlinks. Simply saying, "From the Encyclopedia Britannica online" is not helpful because it can be hard to find the exact page. I haven't come across this problem yet here, but it could be an issue in the long run.
- **Quote if you want to.** I have no problems with someone quoting a source (I know, many don't think we should quote Wikipedia, and that's moot if we don't *use* Wikipedia).
- **Primary sources are awesome.** If you can find an eyewitness testimony to an experiment or a written record by a scientist (or their paper on the experiment/theory), I think you've found the greatest source possible.
- **Multiple sources.** Having one source is all well and good, but you need to have more than just one source. Two or three (in a better-case scenario) show that this information isn't just the ideas of one person. If you can find 10 sources, by all means, list all 10.